# Unable to play a different song using setState method in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

```js
// TuneContainer.js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './TuneContainer.css'

function TuneContainer(props) {
    const[isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)
    const[isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(true)

    const audio = document.querySelector('audio')

    const audioControls = () => {
        if(isPaused) {
                console.log(isPlaying)
                console.log(isPaused)
            setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
            setIsPaused(!isPaused)
                console.log(isPlaying)
                console.log(isPaused)
            audio.play()
        } else {
            setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
            setIsPaused(!isPaused)
            audio.pause()
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="tune-container">
                <div className="info-class">
                    <img src={props.imgsrc} className="tune-img" alt={props.imgalt} onClick={audioControls}></img>
                    <audio src={props.audiosrc} id="tune" loop hidden></audio>
                </div>
            </div>
                    
        </>
    )
}

export default TuneContainer
```

The above is the code for the container which consist of the image, which when clicked plays the song in an infinite loop, until paused again by clicking the image. Below given is the main page which is calling the TuneContainer and passing it props.

```js
// HomePage.js
import React from 'react'
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar'
import TuneContainer from './TuneContainer'
import Bird from '../images/Bird.svg'
import BirdWhistling from '../audios/Bird-whistling.mp3'
import Leaves from '../images/Leaves.svg'
import LeavesRustling from '../audios/Rustling-leaves.mp3'

function HomePage() {
    return (
        <>
            <NavigationBar />
            <div className="container">
                <TuneContainer audiosrc={BirdWhistling} imgsrc={Bird} imgalt="Bird by Ana María Lora Macias from the Noun Project"/>
                <TuneContainer audiosrc={LeavesRustling} imgsrc={Leaves} imgalt="leaves by KP Arts from the Noun Project"/>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

So here, when I click on the bird image, I hear the the chirping sounds, since those are the props passed. The second TuneContainer has different image and audio altogether. However, when the leaf image is clicked, it still plays the chirping sound. So I believe the audio source is not properly getting updated. Can someone please highlight where am I doing a mistake?

***P.S:** Before someone asks, I have checked all the routes and filenames correctly, and no, both audio files have different songs in them.*

---

Although I know the SO highly recommends asking one question in one post, I will just add my second question here, since it is highly related and requires no extra bit of code.

**Q:** When I check the console, the values getting printed (because of the `console.log` statements) are `false, true, false, true`. I believe it should print `false, true, true, false`, since I am printing once before the setState function and once after it. Why such behaviour?

Comment: `useState` is an async function. You will not get the value of it immediately after assigning it. You need to use `useEffect` hook to get its value if u want to perform some activity after state is changed.

Comment: @NeelDsouza I had read about this in some Medium articles, but I thought those were some special cases. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `document.querySelector('audio')` will always return the first html audio element, which in your case is the bird chirping sound.

You can use a unique (id)entifier for each `TuneContainer`. Use that id on your audio tag and query select that id, which will point the correct audio element.

Another way would be to use a `useRef` to get the audio element.

```js
// TuneContainer.js
...
const audioRef = React.useRef(null);
/* const audio = document.querySelector('audio') */

const audioControls = () => {
  if(isPaused) {
    console.log(isPlaying)
    console.log(isPaused)
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
    setIsPaused(!isPaused)
    console.log(isPlaying)
    console.log(isPaused)
    // audio.play()
    audioRef.current.play();
  } else {
      setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
      setIsPaused(!isPaused)
      // audio.pause()
      audioRef.current.pause();
    }
};

...
...
return (
  ...
  ...
    <audio ref={audioRef} src={props.audiosrc} id="tune" loop hidden></audio>
  ...
);
```

Comment: I tried both the methods, and both are working absolutely fine! Thank you so much. Though I will solely stick with the useRef method, since that is far more compact.